# Capture multiple lines using Regular Expression (.Net)

Tags: .net, regex, parsing

I am trying to write a regular expression that can parse the text between < p >< /p > tags.  There will be up to 3 lines of text in a row.  I thought this might be possible using the (?= search ahead feature.

The code that I am currently using to get one line is as follows.

```
<p>([^']*?)<[/]p
```

Is it possible to have one regular expression that can get the text between multiple rows of tags?  Each line would need to be in its own group.

An example would be

```
 <p>The</p>
 <p>Grey</p>
 <p>Fox</p>
```

Comment: Don't forget to have a look at the most voted answer ever: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/please-please-please-dont-use-regex-for-html-tony-the-pony-he-comes/1732454#1732454

Comment: Thanks for link. I have seen that and think I will be safe since this is the only thing from the html I am parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this would be easy using the [Html Agility Pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and you'd get a more robust solution.

But you can do it with regex in certain situations if you're 100% in control of the format and the input is coming from a trusted source:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(html, @"(?:<p>(.*?)</p>\s*)+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (match.Success)
{
    foreach (Capture line in match.Groups[1].Captures)
        Console.WriteLine(line.Value);
}
```

Output:

```
The
Grey
Fox
```

Comment: Accident. Left over from testing. (I did actually test it, honest!)